# Splitting LaTeX string with inline equations using Python

Tags: python

How can I split a LaTeX string that contains text, inline equations, and block of the equation by preserving the order?

I want to split

```
Functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ is related as $$f(x)-g(x)=h(x)$$
```

into

```
['Functions ','f(x)','and','g(x)','is related as ','f(x)-g(x)=h(x)']
```

Comment: Would `['Functions ','f(x)','and','g(x)','is', 'related', 'as','f(x)-g(x)=h(x)']` be acceptable, too ? If so, simply use `"Functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ is related as $$f(x)-g(x)=h(x)$$".split(" ")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using a list comprehension:

```
text_in = "Functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ is related as $$f(x)-g(x)=h(x)$$"
foo = [x.strip() for x in text_in.split("$") if x]
print(foo)
```

This gives you:

```
['Functions', 'f(x)', 'and', 'g(x)', 'is related as', 'f(x)-g(x)=h(x)']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not opposed to using the `regex` library (`re`), then you can easily achieve this with `re.split(pattern, string)`:

```
import re

string = "Functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ is related as $$f(x)-g(x)=h(x)$$"

pattern = "\s\$+|\$+\s"
result = re.split(pattern, string.strip("$"))
```

The pattern will match a whitespace followed by one or more `$` ***or*** one or more `$` followed by a whitespace. It is also worth mentioning that you must use `str.strip("$")` to strip the leading and trailing `$` from the string.

If you are, however, opposed to using `re` to do this, go with [@JonSG's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67875645/12326283)!